# Break the nested (double) loop in Python

Tags: python, nested-loops

I use the following method to break the double loop in Python.

```
for word1 in buf1:
    find = False
    for word2 in buf2:
        ...
        if res == res1:
            print "BINGO " + word1 + ":" + word2
            find = True
    if find:
        break
```

Is there a better way to break the double loop?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Probably not what you are hoping for, but usually you would want to have a `break` after setting `find` to `True`

```
for word1 in buf1: 
    find = False 
    for word2 in buf2: 
        ... 
        if res == res1: 
            print "BINGO " + word1 + ":" + word2 
            find = True 
            break             # <-- break here too
    if find: 
        break
```

Another way is to use a generator expression to squash the `for` into a single loop

```
for word1, word2 in ((w1, w2) for w1 in buf1 for w2 in buf2):
    ... 
    if res == res1: 
        print "BINGO " + word1 + ":" + word2
        break
```

You may also consider using `itertools.product`

```
from itertools import product
for word1, word2 in product(buf1, buf2):
    ... 
    if res == res1: 
        print "BINGO " + word1 + ":" + word2
        break
```

Comment: itertools.product() is a great approach.

Comment: I have learned a something today :)

Answer (score 75):

The recommended way in Python for breaking nested loops is... Exception

```
class Found(Exception): pass
try:
    for i in range(100):
        for j in range(1000):
            for k in range(10000):
               if i + j + k == 777:
                  raise Found
except Found:
    print i, j, k
```

Comment: Really? I've never seen exceptions recommended for anything except, well, exceptional things.

Comment: Really, Python has a bit different approach to exceptions, and this use is OK.

Comment: I like this idea because it also covers situations where you need to iterate over a two-dimensional list with nested for loops. Some other ideas don't work for that because the nested for loop uses the variable provided by the parent for loop to get more than one item to iterate over.

Comment: Plus it doesn't require you to structure your code just so.

Comment: I feel this one is better than the accepted answer.

Comment: I like the answer in general but it does not allow to "continue" instead of "break". Thus it is not so nicely generalizing

Answer (score 18):

Refactor using functions so you can return when you find your "bingo".

The proposal to allow explicit breaking out of nested loops has been rejected:
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3136/

Comment: This should be the top voted answer IMO.

Answer (score 14):

Most times you can use a number of methods to make a single loop that does the same thing as a double loop.

In your example, you can use [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to replace your code snippet with

```
import itertools
for word1, word2 in itertools.product(buf1, buf2):
    if word1 == word2:
        print "BINGO " + word1 + ":" + word2
        break
```

The other itertools functions are good for other patterns too.

Comment: I think you mean `itertools.product`. `combinations` produces n-length tuples from a single sequence

Comment: I think you mean `itertools.product`

Comment: oh bah.... I'm an idiot tonight.