# How to exit outer loop from an inner if statement

Tags: python

I have a loop in the form as below. I want to break and come out of the entire while loop if `p>len(number)`. Number is a list here containing some numbers. 
The below code is not breaking from the entire loop when p is more than the len(number). Can some one help with an implementation in python.

```
while number[p]<0 :
  if "some condition":
    #do something
    p=p+1
    if p>len(number):
        break;
  else:
    #do something
    p=p+1
    if p>len(number)
        break;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Break the nested (double) loop in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597104/break-the-nested-double-loop-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to break out of multiple loops in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops-in-python)

Comment: ...except there aren't actually nested loops here. `if` statements don't count, do they?

Comment: Put the loop in a function and `return`?

Comment: if you're repeating the same code in the `if` and `else` statements, it's a sign that that code doesn't need to be in the `if`/`else` statements.

Comment: The issue is, when p is greater than len(number) the list, it cannot find anything in while loop and so throws an error saying index out of range, hence I need to get out of the while loop the moment p is greater than len(number)

Comment: add that as a condition for your `while` loop, then -- `while p <= len(number) and number[p] < 0`

Answer (score 1):

Please, refer to below two links :

1. PEP 3136 -- Labeled break and continue : https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3136/
2. Rejection of PEP 3136 -- https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-July/008663.html

Hope it will help..

Comment: While links are useful, consider pulling out the relevant information and adding context to make your answer standalone.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your code not to run if `p` is greater than `len(number)`, add it to the conditions for the `while` loop:

```
while p <= len(number) and number[p] < 0:
  if "some condition":
    #do something
  else:
    #do something
  p=p+1
```

There's no need to have the same code repeated in both parts of the `if`/`else` -- just move it out so it's directly under the `while`.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a for loop:

```
for value in number:
    if condition:
        do_something()
    else:
        do_other()
```