# Double while-loop break and jump to line in while loop questions

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, break

I have two questions about while-loop!
I do not want to waste your time, but I really need help.

1, in my code, while true: and another while is existed. I understand that I can break second while-loop, but how can I break first while-loop at the same time?

2, At the end of code "if stand_hit == 'h'; is there anyway coming back to stand_hit == 's'? I do not want it show print(mycard) things after going through stand_hit == h. I do want to pick up new card or stand immidiately.

Thanks! If you do not make sense my question, please comment!

```
while True:

player_card = []
player_card.append(player_draw())
player_card.append(player_draw())
print('your cards:',player_card[0]+player_color,player_card[1]+player_color)
player_total = card_dict[player_card[0]]+card_dict[player_card[1]] 

dealer_card = []
dealer_card.append(dealer_draw())
dealer_card.append(dealer_draw())

dealer_cards = []

for i in dealer_card:
    dealer_cards.append(card_dict[i])

dealer_total = sum(dealer_cards)    
player_card = []

stand_hit = input('(S)tand or (H)it?...: ') 

if stand_hit == 's':

    print('Dealer cards:', dealer_card[0]+dealer_color, dealer_card[1]+dealer_color)

        while dealer_total < 17:

            if dealer_total < 11:
                card_dict['A'] = 11
            elif dealer_total > 10:
                card_dict['A'] = 1

            a = random.choice(list(card_dict))
            print('Dealer drew:', a + dealer_color)
            dealer_total += card_dict[a]

            if dealer_total > 21:
                print('You win!')
                player_score += 1
                print('Dealer:', dealer_score, 'Player:', player_score)
                play_again = input('Play again (Y/N)?...: ')
                if play_again == 'y':
                    print()
                    continue
                elif play_again == 'n':
                    print('\n')
                    print('>_')
                    break



elif stand_hit == 'h':
    a_cards = random.choice(list(card_dict))
    print('You drew:', a_cards + player_color) 
    player_total += card_dict[a_cards]
    stand_hit = 's'

    if player_total > 21:
        print('Dealer wins')
        dealer_score += 1
        print('Dealer:', dealer_score, 'Player:', player_score)
        play_again = input('Play again (Y/N)?...: ')
        if play_again == 'y':
            print()
            continue
        elif play_again == 'n':
            print('\n')
            print('>_')
            break
```

Comment: Wouldn't a simple break break work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4553525/4804629

Comment: @PNX that would merely break the inner while loop

Comment: Why not have a boolean value for the first loop? Then you can change the value of that boolean in the inner loop so the outer loop stops too. `While bln:` and in the inner loop `bln = False`

Comment: @TimStack What do you mean? I don't get it :(

Comment: @splash58, Hi! Thanks for your comment, it that for skip few lines in while-loop?

Comment: It's how to break some  loops

Comment: @splash58, Thank you! Is there any way to skip few lines :(?

Comment: I've left an answer to demonstrate my idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods I can think of to stop the outer loop based on a condition fulfilled in the inner loop.

Pseudo-code:

```
bln = True

while bln:
    # Do stuff
    while x < y:
        if z == n:
            # Break inner loop, and set bln to False to break outer loop
            bln = False
            break
```

A second method:

```
while True:
    bln = False
    # Do stuff
    while x < y:
        if z == n:
            # Break inner loop, and set bln to True for later break statement
            bln = True
            break
    if bln:
        break
```

Note that with the first method the outer loop's iteration will finish, even when `bln` is set to True. The second method will break the outer loop abruptly, however.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you have some times, could you explain me about skipping lines in while-loop as well?

Comment: Glad I could help, don't forget to mark an answer as useful or accept it. Your second question is poorly formulated, I don't understand what you mean. Unfortunately I don't have time to look at it now.