# If exception, break out of the 2nd for loop and continue with what's in the 1st for loop

Tags: python

How to make this nested loop with exceptions print out success, if it catches the NoSuchElementException?

```
for key, value in a.items():
  for key, value in b.items():
    if “abc” not in value:
        driver.get(url)
        try:
            if pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(death, grayscale=True, confidence=.3) is not None:
              driver.close()
            elif pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(death2, grayscale=True, confidence=.3) is not None:
              driver.close()
            elif driver.find_element_by_xpath(element1).is_displayed():
              driver.close()
            else:
                if pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(element2, grayscale=True, confidence=.5) is not None:
                    break
                elif driver.find_element_by_xpath(element3).is_displayed():
                    break
                else:
                    driver.close()
        except NoSuchElementException as nse:
           **GOTO print(‘SUCCESS!’)**
        except Exception as eeee:
            driver.close()
    else:
        print('this should never appear!')

  print(‘SUCCESS!’)
```

Comment: This might answer your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597104/break-the-nested-double-loop-in-python

Comment: Just use `break`.

Comment: That goto statement would break out of **both** loops.  But the post title says just break out of the second loop.  Which is it?

Comment: Workaround with: raise Found;
except Found? I like it. Gonna take a while to test this program out, so appreciate your input if this is correct, and whether I can also use it instead of the other cases with break. Thanks for this, if it works, it's a clean, intuitive solution.

Comment: John, I have used two-space indent there because I had problems with formatting.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  If you only want to break out of the inner loop, then just use `break`, as @PM77-1 said.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: You many not need two loops: `for (key1, value1), (key2, value2) in itertools.product(a.items(), b.items()):`

Comment: You really shouldn't use exceptions for success... that's just wrong on so many levels!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for key, value in a.items():
  _break = False
  for key, value in b.items():
    if “abc” not in value:
        driver.get(url)
        try:
            if pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(death, grayscale=True, confidence=.3) is not None:
              driver.close()
            elif pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(death2, grayscale=True, confidence=.3) is not None:
              driver.close()
            elif driver.find_element_by_xpath(element1).is_displayed():
              driver.close()
            else:
                if pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(element2, grayscale=True, confidence=.5) is not None:
                    break
                elif driver.find_element_by_xpath(element3).is_displayed():
                    break
                else:
                    driver.close()
        except NoSuchElementException as nse:
           _break = True
           break
        except Exception as eeee:
            driver.close()
    else:
        print('this should never appear!')
  if _break:
    break

print(‘SUCCESS!’)
```

you can use a variable to control the outer loop.